# Tinymce Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHeight') on Image

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

I am using     "@tinymce/tinymce-vue": "^3.2.8",
every click on the save on the image picker I got this error.
I can not see any documentation regarding on this part

[image]

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'innerHeight')
```

any solutions for this one?
Thanks!